# Candies Withdrawal Game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are taking out candies one by one from a jar that has 10 red candies, 20 blue candies, and 30 green candies in it. What is the probability that there are at least 1 blue candy and 1 green candy left in the jar when you have taken out all the red candies?

Why is my approach wrong:

$$\frac{2 \cdot 58!}{10! \cdot 29! \cdot 19!} \,\Big / \frac{60!}{10! \cdot 30! \cdot 20!}$$

Reasoning:
There are 2 cases:

1. last candy is green, 2nd last candy is blue
2. last candy is blue, 2nd last candy is green

For each of the cases, where the last and 2nd last candy withdrawn is fixed, there are $\frac{58!}{10!29!19!}$ ways to arrange the rest of the candies. Hence, the numerator.

For the denominator, it is the total number of ways to arrange all the candies, $\frac{60!}{10!30!20!}$.

However, as compared to the answer, $7/12$, my approach seems to be undercounting. Why?

Comment: I'd like to note that when you say *"You are taking out candies one by one from a jar that has 10 red candies, 20 blue candies, and 30 green candies in it."* there is no mention of randomness at all, and you could be choosing the candies you take out, or someone else might be choosing them for you. It's only because you ask *"What is the probability..."* that we start assuming that maybe the candies are being taken out uniformly at random.

Answer (score 6):

You discern two cases ($\cdots bg$ and $\cdots gb$) but there might be more (e.g. $\cdots bggg$).

If $B,G$ denote the number of blue and green candies that are left if all red candies are taken out then to be found is:$$P(B>0,G>0)=1-P(B=0)-P(G=0)+P(B=0,G=0)$$
Note that the last term is actually the probability of the event that the last candie that was taken out is a red one so equals $\frac{10}{60}=\frac16$.

Can you find the other terms yourself?

Hint: in order to find e.g. $P(B=0)$ just ignore all green candies.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your thinking is in your two cases with   $B$  **immediately** followed by $G$ or vice-versa.

- For $B$ to "survive" longest, it must be at the tail of the queue of withdrawals, with $Pr =\frac{b}{b+g+r}$
- To further compute the probability that $G$ survives next longest, we can imagine there are no $B's$
  and thus compute $Pr = \frac{g}{g+r}$
- Thus for surviving longest in the order $BGR$, $Pr = \frac{b}{b+g+r}\cdot\frac{g}{g+r} = \frac{20}{60}\frac{30}{40} = \frac14$
- Similarly, for surving longest in the order GBR, $Pr= \frac{g}{g+b+r}\cdot\frac{b}{b+r} = \frac{30}{60}\frac{20}{30} = \frac13$
- Finally, Pr(R "dies" first) = $\frac14+\frac13= \frac{7}{12}$